# using $_POST values in form alter to add validation

Tags: 7, forms

it's not the first time that i get into trouble using $_post in a node form alter, this time i'd like some assistance.

basically, i need to pass some parameters to a form (and i should not pass the appended to the url, as query parameters). but $_POST values don't work as expected (they work until reaching validation phase).

So.. in a page i pass as hidden value

```
<form method="post" action="/node/add/">
    <input type="hidden" name="mydesideredParameter" value="itsValue">
</form>
```

In the form_alter function of this form, at the very beginning, i try to assign this value to $form_state (and it works, I watchdog it later and it's correct)

```
if (array_key_exists('mydesideredParameter', $_POST)) {
    $form_state['mydesiredConsequence'] = 'dance';
}
```

Later, inside form_alter, at the very end, i state:

```
if ($form_state['mydesiredConsequence'] === 'dance'){
    $form['#validate'][] = 'myDancingFunction';
};
```

No complains happen on form building, but when trying to submit the form, the validation funcion doesn't get called and php complains about index that doesn't exist no more

```
Notice: Undefined index mydesiredConsequence
```

Nothing similar happens when i use this step and the values are in the url(via drupal_query_parameters) , but trying to make this work in $_POST seems a bit awkward. (i obviusly can imagine that the second form-rebuilding ignores $_POST, as it was a former request; but that should be the intended purpose of assigning the value to $form_state).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$form_state['storage']`. This will cache your data and make it available throughout the forms lifecycle.

Comment: I'll try it, but i suppose the index ['storage'] has no special behaviours compared to $form_state['callMeAsYouLikeIt']; it's just a standard naming convention (at least in D7)

Comment: I believe you may be right in it just being a convention but there is not enough context to know what else could be going wrong here.